# drop tablespace if do not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ddl

I have written pl/sql script (works, but doesn't look nice):

```
DECLARE
   v_exists NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) INTO v_exists FROM dba_tablespaces WHERE tablespace_name = 'hr_test';
   IF v_exists > 0 THEN
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLESPACE hr_test INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
   END;
   END IF;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLESPACE hr_RJ DATAFILE ''E:\hr_test_01.dbf'' SIZE 16M';
END;
```

Is there any way to rewrite this script without `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`?

Comment: A better approach would be to not run the `SELECT count(*)` at all - just run the `DROP` and handle the "tablespace not found" exception if it gets raised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You cannot issue DDL statements in static PL/SQL.

And yes, it is perfectly fine to use native dynamic SQL for DDL purposes:

> You need dynamic SQL in the following
>   situations:
>
> You want to execute a SQL data
>   definition statement (such as CREATE),
>   a data control statement (such as
>   GRANT), or a session control statement
>   (such as ALTER SESSION). In PL/SQL,
>   such statements cannot be executed
>   statically.

[Oracle dynamic SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/11_dynam.htm#8845)