# Oracle: Drop all tablespaces that meet a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to drop all tablespaces in my DB that have a particular pattern in their datafile names.

The below query gives me all the tablespaces whose datafile names obey this pattern:

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_DATA_FILES WHERE FILE_NAME LIKE '/vol1/u06%' ;
```

I want to drop all the tablespaces returned by the above query. But I'm unable to figure out how the outer query should be, because `DROP TABLESPACE` doesn't take a `WHERE` clause.
So, the outer query should look like `DROP TABLESPACE tablespace_name.....` where the `tablespace_name` comes one-by-one from the above pattern matching query.

(I'm using Oracle)

Thanks!

Comment: You can make a PLsql block with an execute immediate statement.

Comment: Can you point me to some example of such a usage?

Comment: Here, on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180710/drop-tablespace-if-do-not-exist has exactly what you are asking.

Comment: You just have to change it to a FOR statemant instead of a test with count.

Comment: But how do I pass a variable tablespace name to the 2nd query? The names can be obtained from the 1st query. That's the key problem..

Comment: I provide you an answer. See if it help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you need. But let me say that I would not recommend though because it can be dangerous to delete tablespaces in a dynamic script like this.

```
BEGIN
   FOR rs in (SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME 
                FROM DBA_DATA_FILES WHERE FILE_NAME LIKE '/vol1/u06%')  LOOP
      BEGIN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLESPACE ' || rs.TABLESPACE_NAME || ' INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually dropped the tablespace now using a slightly lengthier method. I output the list of tablespace in a text file. Then I used 'awk' to append the remaining of the query to the left and right of each line of that text file. So the text file now contains a drop query with each tablespace name.